# How to specify WebSphere MQ channel table location for .net web application using web.config

Tags: .net, ibm-mq, mq

I've been going around in circles for a while on this one now.  I'm trying to connect to a distributed queue manager using a supplied channel table file.  I can get this to work if I specify the environmental variable MQCHLLIB and MQCHLTAB on my server.  However the IBM documentation states that the .net config file can override these variables.

Here is what I have placed in my web.config file:

```
...
<configSections>
   <section name="CHANNELS" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
</configSections>

<CHANNELS>
   <add key="ChannelDefinitionDirectory" value="C:\temp"></add>
   <add key="ChannelDefinitionFile" value="DSM_MOM_TEST.tab"></add>
</CHANNELS>
...
```

And here is the code that is executing:

```
Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
//Add managed connection type to parameters.
const String connectionType = MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT;
properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, connectionType);
return new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, properties);
```

queueManagerName is set to the generic queue manager "*Q101T".

However this isn't working and I get an error returned: 2058 MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR

I've been unable to find any more documentation on how to get this to work other than the environmental variables and the standard mqclient.ini should be overriden by the channels stanza in the web.config.

Is there something that I've missed in the code?  Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** I've changed the connectionType to MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED and I'm getting past the error I was getting.  However I'm now getting an I/O error returned:

> System.IO.IOException was unhandled by
>   user code   Message="I/O error
>   occurred."   Source="amqmdnet"
>   StackTrace:
>          at IBM.WMQ.MQChannelTable.CreateChannelEntryLists(MQChannelListEntry
>   nameList)

I think this is most likely related to https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC69174 so I'm now waiting on the middleware guys to confirm if this is the case and hopefully provide me with a new .TAB file...

**Edit2**  Looks like this isn't the problem.  I ran an MQ trace and it's erroring because it can't find the AMQCLCHL.TAB file.  I don't understand why it's still looking for this file.  It should be using the channel table specified in my web.config.  Anyone know why it's not picking up these values?

Answer (score 0):

The .Net configuration file is only used for managed client connection types so switching to managed mode was definitely a step in the right direction.  Now the question is whether the application is actually running in managed mode.  There is a decision tree described in the *[Defining which connection type to use](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzav.doc/un10480_.htm)* section of the Infocenter.  Note that there are cases in which a managed connection can fall back to an unmanaged connection.  I would suggest running through this section to see if any of these cases apply.

Alternatively, try setting the channel table in the mqclient.ini file.  This value is used when not overridden by the .Net configuration file.  If setting the value here works then it confirms that the values in the .Net configuration file are being ignored, presumably because the application is running in unmanaged mode.